# Помогите вспомнить короткий синтаксис для привязки контекста

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

всем кто ложится спать - спокойного сна

я припоминаю что в js был какой-то короткий синтаксис для привязки контекста
что-то навроде ::
но привязать можно не любой контекст как с bind,
а как бы привязываешь к самому себе

но никак не могу вспомнить/нагуглить как это делается.
никто не помнит случайно?

Comment: не было такого синтаксиса

Answer (score 0):

был неправ
это пока только пропозал
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator